# geocoding in excel

Tags: excel, geocoding

I have excel sheet with address column. Latitude and Longitude is required for these addresses.

How to fill next column with 'Latitude' and second next column with 'Longitude' ? Is there any helpful tool ? any suggestion ?

Answer (score 2):

I forked and updated a tool that does this very easily: [Excel Geocoding Tool](http://excelgeocodingtool.com)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain that it can do exactly as you ask but [Google Fusion Tables](http://www.google.com/fusiontables/) has geocoding capabilities

Answer (score 0):

One or more of the below links may provide an API so that you can geocode in Excel. Otherwise, at least some of the sites support the copying and pasting of such data to get the job done manually:

- http://geocoder.us/
- http://www.batchgeo.com/

More urls sans http that you may also find useful, in this form to circumvent stackoverflow filter:

- www.simplegeo.com
- www.vterrain.org/Culture/geocoding.html
- www.mooreds.com/wordpress/archives/296